# How to integrate iMessage keyboard with textfield in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, imessage

I want the ability to send iMessage message in my app. On click of textfield i want iMessage keyboard and send iMessage.Is it possible?.Can i integrate native iMessage in my application?